# No error and no data when copying ListColumn from one table to another with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in two different worksheets and I want to copy a column from one to another.
The tables can be of different size at but any column I copy from the src table will have a matching header in the destination table.

My understanding is that I have to resize the destination table to have the same number of rows as the source table. But after that I should be able to assign the destination range to equal the source range.

The code below runs with no errors but doesn't do anything as far as I can tell.

```
Public Sub SyncListObjects()

    Dim tblDest As ListObject
    Dim tblSrc As ListObject
    Dim mappedCol As ClassTrackedCol

    Set tblDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Power BI Data").ListObjects("tblDest")
    Set tblSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Imported Data").ListObjects("tblSrc")

    'map the matching columns of the tables into a collection
    Set destToSrcColMap = CreateTblToTblColMap(tblDest, tblSrc) 'this works correctly

    tblDest.DataBodyRange.ClearContents

    'the destination table should have the same number of rows as the src
    'but keep it's own number of columns in order to be able to copy
    tblDest.Resize tblDest.Range.Resize(tblSrc.ListRows.Count, tblDest.ListColumns.Count) 


    For Each mappedCol In destToSrcColMap

       Set test1 = tblSrc.ListColumns(mappedCol.ColName).DataBodyRange 'this resolves correctly
       Set test2 = tblDest.ListColumns(mappedCol.ColName).DataBodyRange 'this resolves correctly
       tblDest.ListColumns(mappedCol.ColName).DataBodyRange = _ 
       tblSrc.ListColumns(mappedCol.ColName).DataBodyRange 'this runs but doesn't appear to do anything
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing 2 issues worked for me:

1. Be explicit about the value transfer:

   ```
   tblDest.ListColumns(mappedCol.ColName).DataBodyRange.Value = _ 
      tblSrc.ListColumns(mappedCol.ColName).DataBodyRange.Value
   ```
2. `ListRows.Count` doesn't include the header, so change the following line:

   ```
   tblDest.Resize tblDest.Range.Resize(tblSrc.ListRows.Count, tblDest.ListColumns.Count)
   ```

   to

   ```
   tblDest.Resize tblDest.Range.Resize(tblSrc.Range.Rows.Count, tblDest.ListColumns.Count)
   ```

Comment: beautiful! I had tried the different method of counting the rows already and it wasn't that. Being explicit about the value transfer was what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Great. I think you need to make the second change as well, otherwise the last row doesn't get copied over.